# While using Export-Csv in powershell, how to exclude #TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject from the output

Tags: powershell, csv, service

I am using the following PowerShell script to obtain Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode and PathName of all windows services of a local machine and then export the output to a csv file using the **Export-csv** cmdlet,

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | Select Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, PathName | Export-Csv C:/ListOfServices.csv
```

the script works fine but the problem is, the first row of the output csv file contains

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
```

Is there any way to exclude this line from the output? I am preparing a script to get all these details from all server machines in the network, so excluding this line becomes important.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the `-NoTypeInformation` switch in your `Export-CSV` command, like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service |
Select Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, PathName |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:/ListOfServices.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help, the `-NoTypeInformation` switch works great, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

you need to include **-NoTypeInformation** in export-csv command to avoid

> ## TYPE Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject

ex: `Export-Csv -Path "your path for the export file" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: This is the same answer with the accepted one, who was given 3 years before than your answer.